# .sort() on objects with nested date

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of objects by date, but am not having much luck. Maybe you can see what I am doing wrong?

First I map through an array of objects called 'myBookings'. I then map through the 'posts' property in each object to return the correct post that I want to display on the screen. They look like this, each with different performance dates -

```
{
            "date": "2020-05-01T15:47:37.588Z",
            "type": "show",
            "client": "hey!",
            "clientId": "5e8b54337d9c710ca6f117fa",
            "details": [
                {
                    "title": "Performance Date",
                    "detail": "Fri May 22 2020",
                    "money": 204,
                    "chargeId": "dadbae58-b07d-49ef-b3a8-baf4d18a72e9"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Venue Address",
                    "detail": [
                        "dallas tx",
                        "hey!",
                        [
                            32.7766642,
                            -96.79698789999999
                        ]
                    ],
                    "money": "",
                    "chargeId": "2b2cbe45-32b3-4175-9380-e0ffa5fb58e5"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Base Cost",
                    "detail": "",
                    "money": 20,
                    "chargeId": "4f70d390-fa73-413d-9edc-0b2324442fda"
                }
            ],
            "approved": "pending",
            "total": 224,
            "postId": "175d099e-e6ab-4aa2-9a19-74180b3aeac4",
            "rockOn": []
        }
```

So I have my array of correct posts. I'd like to sort them by Performance Date. The Performance Date is found in the post.details array that has a title of "Performance Date". So I call a .sort on my array of posts. This is where I am having problems - Can you tell me what is wrong with my .sort() function below?

```
        {myBookings.map( band => {
                return band.posts.map(post => {
                    if(post.clientId === user.sub.slice(6, user.sub.length)){
                        console.log(post)
                        return post
                    }
                })
            }).sort( (a, b) => {
                return new Date(a.details.filter(detail => {
                    if(detail.title === "Performance Date"){
                        return detail.detail 
                        } 
                    })) - new Date(b.details.filter(detail => { 
                        if(detail.title === "Performance Date"){
                            return detail.detail 
                            } }))
            })}
```

Comment: What is going on in that sort comparator? Why the filtering and Date casting?

Comment: Hey Mike! Thanks for the comments so far. I was filtering to get into the 'performance date' part of the post.. Then I was using the new Date() to convert it into a date object. In my head it could compare them that way... hmm So I need to get that date into a type of number to sort it?

Comment: I'd start by simplifying this code: instead of filter, use `find`. Because right now you're passing _an array_ (because that's what filter yields) into the `new Date` constructor, and you're trying to make filter return some value, which it can't: it's job is to throw things away if you return a falsey value, and keep things if they're truthy. It completely ignores what you _actually_ return, so the general rule is to stick with what filter needs: return a boolean. (but in this case: don't even use filter. Use find)

Comment: Alright! I'll work with it a bit more! Thanks for your input.